# Exclude some entity's property on validate

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have this entity

```
public class Account : ValidationModel, IFormattable
{
    private int id;
    private string cardNumber;
    private string username;
    private string password;
    private string fullName;
    ......

    public Account()
    {
        this.id = 0;
        this.username = String.Empty;
        this.password = String.Empty;
        this.fullName = String.Empty;
        ................
    }
    public int Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { SetProperty(ref id, value); }
    }
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "EnterUsername", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
            public string Username
    {
        get { return username; }
        set { SetProperty(ref username, value); }
    }
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "EnterCardNumber", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
    public string CardNumber
    {
        get { return cardNumber; }
        set { SetProperty(ref cardNumber, value); }
    }
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "EnterPassword", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources))]        
    public string Password
    {
        get { return password; }
        set { SetProperty(ref password, value); }
    }
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "EnterFullName", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
  .......
}
```

When I want to validate this entity I call accountInstance.Validate() like this

```
string errorMessage = account.Validate();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(errorMessage))
                {
                    messageService.ShowError(errorMessage);
                    return;
                }
```

It will validate all properties. Now, I want to exclude the ID, Password, Username
How to I do it in C# without make change to the DataContext of Entity Framework ?

Comment: You can use FoolProof custom validators. There are lot of options in that library. May be you get some help from them.

Comment: You need to look for conditional validation. Try this search site:stackoverflow.com conditional validation entity framework